# Is there any chance of testing the PostgreSQL database in this scenario without duplicating the database in the development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

“I have a Rails application with PostgreSQL database. My database contains 1000 records in it. 
I have written a rake task which will manipulate the records in the database. 
If the rake task went wrong i want to revert back the changes to the original in the database.
is there any chance of testing the database in this scenario without duplicating the database in the development environment ?”

Comment: You could back up the database before mangling it. If things go wrong, you just restore the backup

Answer (score 4):

In Rails itself having the feature **sandbox**

If you wish to test out some code without changing any data, you can do that by invoking rails console --sandbox.

```
 bin/rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox 
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0>
```

**You can paste your ruby code here and can see the changes you wanted to see. while closing this console, All your changes will be reverted back(running as a transactional)**

For more informations you can refer this link 
**http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console**

Answer (score 1):

you can duplicate a database in same env.

```
create database test with template original_db;
```

Will create cop of existing db, on which you can run your tests, specifying test instead of original db name in connections string